# How to expose a simple rabbitmq deployment on K8S (Minikube) using a yml-file?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, minikube

I am trying to expose my RabbitMQ deployment and access it on my browser. For the deployment I created the following yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
    name: blur-rabbitmq
    labels:
        app: blur-rabbitmq
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: blur-rabbitmq
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: blur-rabbitmq
        spec:
            containers:
            - name: blur-rabbitmq
              image: rabbitmq:3-management
              ports:
              - containerPort: 15672
```

And for the service the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: blur-service
  labels:
    app: blur-rabbitmq
spec:
  selector:
    app: blur-rabbitmq
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15672
```

After creating the deployment and the service I expected to access the homepage of RabbitMQ on localhost:8080 but its not working. What am I missing? Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either port forward a local port to the cluster via [`kubectl port-forward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) or you need to create an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) object to map a public IP to the service endpoint within the cluster.

Basically, the cluster has its own internal network, and you need to instruct Kubernetes to "punch a hole" for you to access the service endpoint within that network from outside.

Comment: Got it. I will try here. Thanks!